# PHP, вывести список месяцев за определенный интервал в обратном порядке

Tags: php

Необходимо вывести список месяцев в формате:

Февраль 2018 
Январь 2018 ... 
Декабрь 2015

```
public static function all_months()
    {
        $months = array('Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь');
        $dateStr = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2015-12-01"));
        $dateEnd = date("Y-m-d");
        $end = new DateTime($dateEnd);
        $begin = (new DateTime($dateStr));
        $periods = new DatePeriod($begin, new \DateInterval('P1M'), $end);
        echo '<selecet>';
        foreach ($periods as $period) {
            $num = $period->format("n");
            echo "<option value='{$period->format('Y')}'>{$months[$num - 1]} {$period->format('Y')}</option>";
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
```

Но DateInterval выводит Декабрь 2015  ... Январь 2018 Февраль 2018

Как можно отсортировать этот список объектов в обратном порядке?

Comment: Есть функция array_reverse() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reverse.php А может и интервал отрицательный задать можно при формировании массива.

Comment: array_reverse() нельзя использовать, ибо expects parameter 1 to be array, object given. При этом превращать сначала в массив неудобно, потом передавать во view хз как. Обратный интервал задать, просто поменяв начало и конец местами, нельзя.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось, если использовать (array_reverse(iterator_to_array($periods))

```
 foreach (array_reverse(iterator_to_array($periods)) as $period) {
                $num = $period->format("n");
                echo "<option value='{$period->format('Y')}'>{$months[$num - 1]} {$period->format('Y')}</option>";
            }
```